# Is there an actively maintained DOM implementation for C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, html, dom

I'm looking for a DOM implementation that I can use on HTML5 documents in C#.

Requirements are:

- Parse HTML5
- Query the DOM through some means
- Manipulate the DOM (create and inject nodes, remove nodes, move nodes, merge/nest other DOMs)
- Obtain the DOM after manipulations as a string
- Ideally the library would be under active development

*Note: I'm aware of Html Agility Pack, however I'm interested in seeing if I have any other options available as it hasn't been maintained since 2010.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to attempt to make the html5 wellformed, using [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader) which is also hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/MindTouch/SGMLReader). It looks like the latest commit to the master branch was 11 months ago.

> SGMLReader is a versatile C# .NET library written by Chris Lovett for parsing HTML/SGML files.

It attempts to convert malformed html documents into wellformed xml documents. You can then manually manipulate the document however you choose.